# AngularJS $Http Service to GET json Not Showing

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Trying to get json data. Originally created an ajax requests that works in a regular html page but not in my angular app so I decided to try the built in $http get function. I get no errors with this, however, my ajax data does not come in, though in console log it shows the GET worked.

My php displays an encoded json object array which shows up fine when i browse right to it.

My controller looks like:

```
    apDash.controller('fieldopmgrController', function($scope,$http){
        $http.get('protected/getHeadObs.php')
            .success(function( data, status, headers, config ) {
        $scope.flights = data.flightid;
           });  
    });
```

My view looks like:

```
    <div class="small-5 columns"> 
       <label>Flight ID
          <select name="fliID" class="radius">
          <option ng-repeat="flight in flights">{{flight.flightid}}</option>
          </select>
       </label>
    </div>
```

My json looks like:

**image updated!**

[image]

Again, i get absolutely no errors in my console log but yet my view does not work. Been toying with AngularJS for a few months but this is my first time im using the $http service. Any help with getting it to show up/advice on what im doing wrong would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by encoding my row's in json. As stated above in many of the comments, my json was not formatted correctly. In my service I went in and encoded each row individually and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and guess that your ajax response didn't have a flightid property located on a flightid property. Have you tried `{{ flight }}`? Also, in order for the ng-repeat to work, you need to assign an array of objects to `$scope.flights`

Comment: Just updated my question with a screen shot of my json. I tried flight but still doesn't return me a flightid in my <option></option> element.

Comment: is it in an array with potential for other flight objects? it must be in an array for ng-repeat to iterate through. it looks like if it were the first item in an array, you would assign the array "flights" as ```$scope.flights = flights;``` and access the flight in the options ```flight['FieldOpsData']['flightid']```

Comment: It is a record set with autogenerated id's for flightid. There can only be 1 flight id assigned to a row. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'flight['FieldOpsData']['flightid']' in my <options></options> element?

Comment: you can't iterate over a set of records if there is only one record and they don't come in a set. I was using bracket notation to access the properties

Comment: there has got to be a way to get each flightid. I do not have the option of bringing the flight id's back in an array.

Comment: are the flights themselves coming in an array? you seem unable to answer this question. please provide the actual data response and not a partial screenshot.

Comment: I just uploaded a larger screenshot of my json array.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without looking at the JSON output, but it seems like this line is incorrect:

```
$scope.flights = data.flightid;
```

Did you mean to say?

```
$scope.flights = data;
```

Comment: i updated my question just a few mins ago with my json. @AlekseyDmitriyev

Comment: Data returns me back a bunch of angular erros... $scope.flights = data;

Comment: errors say: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: flight in flights, Duplicate key: string:

Comment: I did try this and then it froze my browser... had to force quit it.

Comment: <option ng-repeat="flight track by $index" value="{{flight}}">{{flight}}</option> gives me the result: "Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'flight track by $index'."

Comment: because you didn't write ```flight in flights track by index```

Comment: we can't debug your screenshot. sorry. from what you're showing, it's not even an array.

Comment: your JSON doesn't seem to be iteratable as @adrichman said above

Comment: Ok i will try and restructure my json.

Comment: @AlekseyDmitriyev i was able to convert my json object to an array... i updated my screenshot in my question. however, im still getting: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: flight in flights track by $index